# What do you call the movement associated with the hula hoop?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the movement associated with the hula hoop? The hula hoop is a popular toy, but I am wondering if there's a particular verb associated with it and a particular noun associated with the movement. What do we call it?

I was thinking of swirl and swirling, but I think it might be too general.

For example:

> He swirled on his hula hoop.
>
> He was moving his hula hoop with swirls.

None of these sentences sound natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gyrate:** gy·rate  (jī′rāt′)
intr.v. gy·rat·ed, gy·rat·ing, gy·rates
1. To revolve around a fixed point or axis.
2. To move in a spiral or spirallike course. See Synonyms at turn.
3. To oscillate or vary, especially in a repetitious pattern